# Java readline() performance differs on subsequent tests

Tags: java, file, caching, memory, io

I wrote program to read content from a simple 1GB file using a simple buffered reader.

I recorded the time from start to finish, as to calculate the time used.

An interesting observation I have made is that on the first run, the reading speed came out to about 80~90MB/s, but when I ran it a second time, it reads considerably faster, and at a speed of around 320MB/s.

I guess this might be a result of a memory caching problem, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Seems like disk caching (either on the disk's physical cache, or your OS'es memory mapped cache) is causing the speedup on the second run. Why is this a problem?

Comment: Caching, JIT, and classes don't have to be re-loaded on the second attempt.

Comment: @MadConan caching a class isn't going to triple how fast you can read from disk. While this may be a factor, it is almost certainly because of read caching.

Comment: @ChrisSprague Yes, I realized that after my initial comment.  I edited it, although it's a bit vague.

Comment: What would count as fixing it?

Comment: A BIT NOTICE HERE: I am currently using the lab machine, so the sudo command is not available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If caching is the problem, you should be able to use the [method detailed here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87909/93571) to clear your cache, assuming you're on a Linux system. This method requires super user access.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but is there any method to solve this, if sudo command is not available?

Comment: @fTTTTT unfortunately, it looks like that solution requires super user access due to (among other things) accessing `/proc`. What kind of content is in the file you're using? If the contents are randomly generated, tracked elsewhere, or are blank, you may be able to get away with removing and recreating the file between each program call. That way, what you read (probably) won't remain in the cache.

Comment: @fTTTTT e.g., `rm testfile.txt; truncate -s 1g testfile.txt`... but you lose what was in that original file this way.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you want to do is to compare the speed difference between `readline` and some other methods of reading in a 1GB file and you are getting conflicting results from running `readline` a couple of times?

Perhaps randomize the file contents, or read different files.